# what can be used instead of IVideoSource IVideoFrameConsumer in rtc2 for communcation channel in agora sdk 4.2.6

Tags: agora.io

need to implement consumeByteArrayFrame method which required
IVideoFrameConsumer  what alternative can be used instead of IVideoFrameConsumer and IVideoSource for communication channel in version 4.2.6

i tried using IVideoSource IVideoSin IVideoFrameConsumer but it does not support version 4.2.6 for communication channel

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that Stack Overflow is not made to ask for tutorial, video or book/technologie recommendation. Please use Stack Overflow to get help with code and see [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.